# MDX aggregate out a dimension

Tags: mdx

I'm trying to compute outcome frequencies, i.e., count divided by total.

I can't work out how to get a total in MDX.

Data looks like this.

[image]

The *fact* is just a 1 so their sum is the number of experiments with the given outcome.

It's easy in SQL

```
SELECT Session, Outcome, fi / N AS p
FROM (
    SELECT Session, Outcome, CAST(COUNT(*) AS float) AS fi, CAST(SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY Session) AS float) AS N GROUP BY Session, Outcome
) T
```

Is it possible in MDX? If so: how?

I've tried these:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.Measures.Experiments AS SUM([Outcomes] , Measures.[Actual Outcome]);
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.Measures.ExperimentsA AS SUM([Outcomes].[(All)] , Measures.[Actual Outcome]);
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.Measures.ExperimentsAM AS SUM([Outcomes].AllMembers , Measures.[Actual Outcome]);
```

The first and third just give `(null)` and the second is just the same as the existing measure -- which makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Experiments]
AS
    SUM([Outcomes].[All], [Measures].[Actual Outcomes])
;
```

So: what is the difference between `[All]` and `[(All)]`?

Comment: Actually, `.[All]` and `.[(All)]` seem to be behaving the same now.

I don't understand. I just don't understand. And the worst thing is that I don't understand how to find out the anwser. All I can do is trial and error, not even trial and improvement.

Comment: not too sure about [(All)] but `SUM([Outcomes].[All], [Measures].[Actual Outcomes])` looks standard for calculating a sum across all members of a dimension.